# BEL in Bash / Zsh PROMPT

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt, zshrc

I do have the following config in my .zshrc:

```
BEL=$(tput bel)
PROMPT+='%(?::$BEL)'
```

That works/worked in some environment (always Cygwin on Windows), but currently does not anymore.

(Same behaviour: not working, in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.)

What is wrong?

Comment: Make sure the `PROMPT_SUBST` option is enabled.

Comment: I wouldn't ever expect that to work in bash; `%(x.true-text.false-text)` is a zsh-ism.

Comment: Would there be a generic way that'd work for both env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `zsh`, unlike `bash`, parameter expansions embedded in a prompt are only expanded when the prompt is displayed if the `PROMPT_SUBST` option is set.

`%(...)` is a `zsh`-specific escape sequence, and `PROMPT` itself is a `zsh`-specific name, so this will not work in `bash`, which would require something like

```
PS1+='$(if test $? -ne 0; then tput bel; fi)'
```

(which, incidentally, would work in `zsh` as well, assuming `PROMPT_SUBST` were enabled. A command that would conditionally enable it if the current shell is, in fact, `zsh`, might be

```
if [ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
  setopt PROMPT_SUBST
fi
```

Comment: FYI, the operand -neq should be rewritten -ne